# XCode not able to get Adhoc provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, macos, configuration, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have two provisioning profiles in my system. One is for the app store and another is for ad-hoc provisioning. When I am trying to upload ad-hoc it is always showing app store provisioning profile instead of the ad-hoc profile. I am not getting a change option.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: At least tell us which version of Xcode you are using.

Comment: Is the Ad hoc profile installed on your mac?

Comment: Yes. Ad hoc profile installed on my mac.

Comment: @Lumialxk I am using xcode 8.1

Comment: Where are you uploading the adhoc build?  You can't submit an ad hoc build to Apple.